# run cucumber through command prompt || Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Tags: maven, command, pom.xml, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to run cucumber tag through command line(Windows env). I configured pom.xml and maven properly. I hit command like ----

D:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin> **mvn clean -f E:\gitClone\demoBDDFramework test -Dcucumber.options="E:\gitClone\demoBDDFramework\src\main\java\com\assetvantage\featureFile --gule E:\gitClone\demoBDDFramework\src\main\java\com\assetvantage\StepDefination --tags @SmokeTest" -e**

D:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin> **mvn clean -f E:\gitClone\demoBDDFramework test -Dcucumber.options="../src/main/java/com/assetvantage/featureFile --tags @SmokeTest" -e**

D:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin> **mvn clean -f E:\gitClone\demoBDDFramework test -Dcucumber.options="-tags @SmokeTest" -e**

and output is mentioned below

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.879 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-21T14:24:39+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------[eclipse project structure][1]
```

Please suggest.

Attached my pom.xml
[CMD output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bcYH.png)
[Eclipse project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO6ZR.png)

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a typo in the command line. 
"--gule", should be "--glue" in the first place.